# alert JSON element by using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i am trying to alert a `JSON` element using `JQuery` , here is my code:

data.js JSON data

```
[
    {
  "name": "bader",
  "major": "medicine",
  "id": "334453"
    }
]
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $.getJSON("data.js", function(json) {
   alert("JSON Data: " + json.name);
 });



});
```

i tried to inspect element i had this error on my consol

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///data.js. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

i am still very new to handling `JSON` and `JQUERY` , i do not know where i went wrong here , if someone could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file:///data.js` indicates that you are loading the page directly from your local file system.

[Browsers have restrictions for Ajax request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), they don't allow access to remote domains (if the remote domain does not allow it) or local files (though this can be enabled afaik (somehow, depends on the browser)).

The easiest way, IMHO, is to access your file through a server, not from the file system.
If you have Python, you can simply start a local server in the current directory with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. That's enough for testing and better than local file system access.

---

Regarding the output: `json` will be an array, so you have to access the `name` of the first object with `json[0].name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data.js",
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType:"application/json",
  success: function(data)
  {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t"))
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, your JSON is malformed it should start with curly braces {[{name:"",blah}]}

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ says it's valid. Why do you think it is invalid? *edit:* No, the top level "element" has either to be an array or object. `{[{name:"",blah}]} ` on the other side is totally incorrect.

Comment: It might work just fine for javascript, but in other languages it won't work. Just trying to keep to best practices!

Comment: thanks , but the issue was that i am not working on webserver enivornment

Comment: It should, because it is valid according to the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Access it like this

```
json[0].name
```

because [] brackets are array operators.